# Video in background div not working on IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, video, html5-video

So I'm trying to implement this really cool effect on my portfolio site, it's a looped video playing in a background div(no audio). I got the idea from this site: http://www.eclarify.com

I was able to get it working in every browser **except for IE** (well and iOS/Nexus, but I'll figure out a static image fallback for those).

However I can see the video playing at [eclarify](http://www.eclarify.com/) on my IE, and I can't find what they are using to enable that cross-browser functionality.

**Here is my site:** http://leongaban.com | **My CodePen:** http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/IBpyb

**HTML:**

```
<div class="clouds">
    <video width="1920" height="1080" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload>
        <source src="videos/clouds.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
        <source src="videos/clouds.ogg" type="video/ogg" >
        <source src="videos/clouds.webm" type="video/webm" >
        <object data="videos/clouds.mp4" width="1920" height="1080">
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
            <param name="autoplay" value="true" >
            <param name="loop" value="true" >
            <embed src="videos/clouds.swf" width="1920" height="1080" wmode="transparent" >
        </object>
    </video> 
</div>

<header>
    <div id="main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#content">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#footer">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="logo-title">
        <img src="images/leon_gaban.png" width="256" height="256" class="avatar" />

        <h1>Hello, I'm Leon Gaban</h1>
        <h2>Web Designer &amp; Developer</h2>
        <h3>I believe that successful design succeeds in telling the best story</h3>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.clouds {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.clouds video, div.clouds object, div.clouds embed {
    /*width: 100%;*/
    width: 2000px;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 720px;
    margin: 0 auto;  
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    /*background: #ededed;*/
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Internet Explorer does not recognize the video format as something he can play in a `<video>`-tag. If you try to open a video directly, e.g. "[/videos/clouds.mp4](http://leongaban.com/videos/clouds.mp4)", the IE shows a dialog to play it using the Windows Media Player. So what you can try and what will most likely help is to explicitly add the video formats in your `.htaccess`-file like this:

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/ogg .ogv
```

Comment: I will add that tonight too! Also tried my mp4 link inside of IE and I actually saw it load in the browser, only it was lagging horribly. Looked like it was paused for several secs, I will try the htaccess file and reducing the file size too

Comment: IE9 can be very iffy about videos. Especially about how many video tags on a page, video format, file size, resolution etc. and the playback capabilities differ extreme from system to system and depend a lot on the bandwidth.

Comment: Hi @insertusernamehere would my htaccess file look like this? I've never made one before:<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
Options -Indexes
order deny,allow
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/ogg .ogv

Comment: The deny rules are only important if you want to disable access to certain files. If no other stuff is needed in the `.htaccess` at the moment create one using only the lines from the answer and store it in the root directory of your web folder - i.e. most likely where your index file is placed.

Comment: ah thanks!!! I was putting it in the videos folder :) also I think I actually created the file correctly this time...

Answer (score 2):

I forked your CodePen and replaced your video assets with the eClarify assets which confirmed my suspicion that the issue us with your video assets. See http://codepen.io/Lafinboy/pen/AhFlt.

I would suggest reducing the size (file and physical) of the video assets and export them again.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out as soon as I get home :D

Comment: Hmm I've re-exported out the video, it's now less in size then eCalrify's video. It's not working in my IE at home, but I do now see it working in my CodePen: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/IBpyb so strange, will check on my PC at work tomorrow!